# How to dismiss dialog box before further processing?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `alertDialog` that takes input for further processing. Because the processing can take a while, I want to close the `alertDialog` and display an image during the time it is doing the process method. The problem is that  `process()` is called before the dialog is actually dismissed. So during that loading time the program basically 'hangs', displaying the alert dialog until `process()` finishes, after which the image is shown for a split second, defeating its purpose.

I have tried showing the image in the `process()` method, and tried doing `dialog.dismiss()` in a synchronized method, but the result stays the same.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

         final String input = et.getText().toString();

         dialog.dismiss(); //finish this first

         process(input); //then do this

    }
});

 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Just start `process` on a different thread?

Comment: I'm new to coding, so I apologize if I'm doing this wrong. I tried putting the process(input) inside an anonymous subclass of Thread, but I still get the same result, besides it completing a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
 final String input = et.getText().toString();
 dialog.dismiss();

 // run in background
 AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     process(input);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new 
    DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //do work on dismiss of dialog
            }
    });
```

So,you can show the image in this section and start your process as well. Add a callback listener to process end and use the callback to make the image invisible when the process ends.

Comment: This still prioritized the  process(input) and showed the image afterwards unfortunately. Thank you for your answer.